# How to calculate the rate of interest in compound interest problem using python

Tags: python

I know how to calculate compound interest in python using this function:

```
def compound_interest(principal, rate, time):
 
    # Calculates compound interest
    Amount = principal * (pow((1 + rate / 100), time))
    CI = Amount - principal
    print("Compound interest is", CI)
```

I want to input the principal amount, final amount, time to the function and it should output the rate. how do I do that?

Comment: Are you lacking the math formula or are you struggling to implement it?

Comment: math formula is fine but I am not able to get the t root of A/P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to rearange your formula.

```
rate = (100 * (final_amount/principal)**(1/time)) - 100
```

in function:

```
def rate_interest(principal, final_amount, time):
    rate = (100 * (final_amount/principal)**(1/time)) - 100
    print("Compound interest rate is", rate, "%")
```

Comment: i change to function